# How to use hook to hijack cudaSetDevice and modify device id？

Tags: cuda, gpu, hook, ld-preload

I want to hijack cudaSetDevice with hook(LD_PRELOAD) and modify the device id. After the hijacking is successful, the gpu task submission will be wrong.

I tried to hijack the cuCtxCreate function in the driver api, but I couldn't hijack it. The same method hijacks the cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain function, which can be hijacked and an error will occur when modifying the device id.

```
// cuda 9.0 cuda runtime api   
typedef int(*cuda_set_device_fp)(int);

// define dynamic library same name function
int cudaSetDevice(int device)
{
  static void *handle = NULL;
  static cuda_set_device_fp orig_cuda_set_device = NULL;

  if( !handle )
  {
    handle = dlopen("libcuda.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    orig_cuda_set_device = (cuda_set_device_fp)dlsym(handle, "cudaSetDevice");
  }
  device = 1;
  printf("oops!!! hack function invoked. device = %d\n", device);
  return cudaSetDevice(device);
}
```

The hijacking succeeds, mapping the user to the gpu task on device 0 and re-mapping to device 1.

Comment: Please try to provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

In the provided source code at the end of your function you recursively call your function again, instead of calling orig_cuda_set_device with the modified device id. This causes infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried not to modify the device ID, hijacking was successful. However, my goal is to hijack cudaSetDevice and modify the device ID. Is it possible to understand that the function parameters hijacked by the dynamic link library can not be modified?